# NSNumberFormatter numberFromString: and kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude give an error of unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to get a latitude information from an image. According to docs `kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude` returns `CFStringRef` type. But when I try to convert it to a number using `numberFromString:` it gives an error at runtime:

> -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000002261e0

```
CFStringRef latitude;

if (CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(gpsDict, kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude, (const void **)&latitude))
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
    NSString *str = (__bridge NSString*)latitude;
    NSLog(@"str %@", str);
    NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:str]; <-- error here
    ...
}
```

`latitude` and `str` exist and can be logged as `42.37637833333334`.

If I create a string myself (`str = @"42.37637833333334"`) then NSNumberFormatter works as expected. For some reason it doesn't like the original latitude string.

What's going on here, why this error?

Comment: It sure looks a lot like the dictionary value is an NSNumber, not an NSString.  Can you see what happens with this `NSNumber *num = (__bridge NSNumber*)latitude;` then just log that and skip the formatter logic?

Comment: @danh yes, casting to NSNumber works, thank you. But it's hard to believe no one ever discovered `kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude` is actually a number and not a string as documented. The image comes from iPhone, and its dictionary was written by iOS.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand that either.  That's why I commented rather than answering.  What happens when you do this: `id value = (__bridge id)latitude;` then log `[value class]`?

Comment: It logs `__NSCFNumber`

Comment: Yes, weird. Also, that does make more sense for the type of a latitude value, doesn’t it? And yet, you probably did the same thing I did: look at the docs, see the string type, rub your eyes and look again.

Comment: I'm still thinking I must be doing something wrong :) I don't understand how it went unnoticed if it was like that from the beginning. But if I'm not the only one who see it, I'll report it to Apple and see what they'll say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182524/discussion-between-indoor-and-danh).